# ElasticSearch regex query doesn't work

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am using ES 2.4.6 with Java 8, and i created a document object as following:

```
@Document(indexName = "airports", type = "airport")
public class Airport {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Field(type = String)
  private String name;
}
```

And i successfully search several airport objects to ES, with following
names: **"San Francisco", "San Mateo", "Santiago", "Palo Alto", "Big San"**
The JSON content inside ES looks like following:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "airports",
        "_type": "airport",
        "_id": "SSMlsTWIYefbXHCnYEwEY",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "SSMlsTWIYefbXHCnYEwEY",
          "name": "Santiago"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "airports",
        "_type": "airport",
        "_id": "LlDcKuywPjURNeIISjXLjC",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "LlDcKuywPjURNeIISjXLjC",
          "name": "San Mateo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "airports",
        "_type": "airport",
        "_id": "CVIjEHYphSmZIjYbHCMwtkqfKWtEHVh",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "CVIjEHYphSmZIjYbHCMwtkqfKWtEHVh",
          "name": "San Francisco"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "airports",
        "_type": "airport",
        "_id": "gbntKR",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "gbntKR",
          "name": "Palo Alto"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "airports",
        "_type": "airport",
        "_id": "bKosUdHeseMMboyaejv",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "bKosUdHeseMMboyaejv",
          "name": "Big San"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then i have following curl command to use regex query to find all airport 
names staring with **"san"** ignoring case, i did:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/airports/airport/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "name": "^(?i)san"
        }
    }
}
'
```

I use the regex "^(?i)san" directly match against those airport names,
it works as expect:

```
String regex = "^(?i)san";
assertTrue("San Francisco".matches(regex));
assertTrue("San Mateo".matches(regex));
assertTrue("Santiago".matches(regex));
assertTrue(!"Big San".matches(regex));
```

So does anyone know why ES regex query returns empty result back? Now, if
i use **"san"** as regex, all 4 names return back, and if i use **"San"**, nothing returns back.

Comment: If you want to get names starting with `san` or `San`, try `"name": "[sS]an.*"`

Comment: It does not work. i only want the names starting with "san" ignoring case. And why normal java regex does not work here? And in real production, "san" will be runtime parameter passed in. I will prefer "^(?i)" +name+".*" as regex

Comment: You cannot expect ES regex that is of Lucene flavor to support java.util.regex. Its patterns are always anchored and you should not use `^`. `(?i)` is not supported in Lucene regex flavor. `"name": "[sS][aA][nN].*"` is your only option with that regex.

Comment: "Big San" got returned when i used "[sS]an.*".  To get starting with, i have to use anchor "^" according to the ES doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax

Comment: That means the pattern is not handled by the ES (Lucene) regex engine. Acc. to the docs you provided, *Lucene’s patterns are always anchored. The pattern provided must match the entire string.* and the `^` is not supposed to be there. See the examples. And that means your question is now unclear.

Comment: You said "Lucene's pattern are always anchored." where does it come from? If it always anchored, "Big San" should not be returned. This is contradicting with "must match the entired string". My question is very clear: to find out all names starting with "san" ignoring case. Can ES allow do it? So far, i haven't got any solution from your comments yet. But thanks for your efforts.

Comment: OK, after more tests, i agree with you that: if I pass "san", then it will search and return all airport names starting with "san" ignoring case. If I use "san.*" as regex, we not only return starting and ending, we will also return airport names containing "san" ignoring case as well.

Comment: I haven't tried in newer ES release. These may changed after 5.6 release.

Comment: @Yongqin. If I get your problem correctly , you want to search for airports that start with a particular prefix ignoring case. Is that correct? If yes, there are other queries in elasticsearch which can help you solve this problem. I can specify one if you are fine to use other queries

Comment: @Richa. Yes, please let me know.

Comment: From my comments, the main point is that your code does not seem to parse the regex with the ES (Lucene) regex engine. So, you may try more variations, like `(?i)^San.*` that is a valid Java regex fitting the `matches` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Match Phrase Prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) for the problem mentioned above.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
       "name": "San"
      }
    }
 }
```

See if it resolves your problem.

Comment: I tried this query before. It doesn't work. it returns empty list back.

Comment: I tried and it worked.. What is the mapping of your index? and What ES version are you using?

Comment: Please see the top of this question.

Comment: Sorry I missed it. So `name` is of type `String` which is `analyzed` by default. So ideally above query should work.  I have the same mapping and its is working

Comment: See my command line result:curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/airports/airport/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>     "query": {
>         "match_phrase_prefix":{
>             "name": "san"
>         }
>     }
> }
> '
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}

Comment: Can you please confirm if `name` is `analyzed`.. Please show the output of `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/airports/airport/_mapping'`

Comment: {
  "airports": {
    "mappings": {
      "airport": {
        "properties": {
          "faaCode": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "iataCode": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "icaoCode": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I am still not sure why your query is not returning any results? I have got same mapping in my system and it is working perfectly fine.